Side Angle Perimeter congruence for triangles
From Euclid we have the triangle congruences SSS (side-side-side),  SAS( side-angle-side), ASA, AAS,  HL (hypotenuse-Leg right triangle only).
We could also have SAP (side-angle-perimeter) congruence. Idea is put the side of known length between two foci of ellipse.  The (perimeter length - known side length) is sum of distance from foci.  Is there a way to prove this using the geometry such as ratio of lengths and angles? (Dandelin spheres are a nice way to prove the sum of distance from foci on ellipse is constant.)
Know length AB, Angle ABC,  and sum AB + BC + CA.
Congruent to another triangle with the same SAP. Ellipse is just to help with proof. Put A and B at foci and C on ellipse. Then all triangles with same AB and perimeter must have C on same ellipse.  The angle fixes where on ellipse.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A congruency axiom can be proved true if it allows us to compute the area of the triangle using only the data collected.

From what I understand, you mean to say that  a known side of a triangle is put between 2 foci of an ellipse, and the 3rd point of the triangle is projected on the circumference. By property of ellipse, the sum of the other two unknown sides produced is constant. But this can be true for any value of the unknown sides. How does it prove congruency then?

Added picture. Hope that helps.

@kirkbeatty Okay yes it's a possible axiom I guess. Equal sides are known. Angle is known. It allows us to picture a line segment and a ray coming out from a single point. The end of the line segment is connected to any random point in the ray. As the sum of the sides is constant, only one connection is possible. Hence yes it's a modified version of ASA

This should also work if the known angle is opposite the known side.

A simple proof can be given by contradiction, for instance.

From your diagram, we know the value of $a+b+c, \angle ABC $ and $c$. Thus we know the value of $a+b=k$(say).
By cosine law,
$$b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\angle ABC$$
$$\implies b^2=(k-b)^2+c^2-2(k-b)c\angle ABC$$
Thus we get a linear expression w.r.t $b$(the $b^2$ cancels out). As only a single value of $b$ is possible, it's a valid axiom

You are right.  I could just use Euclid book II (second book) proposition 12.  Need to drop perpindicular down from C onto major axis of AB to point D.   Then BD = -c cosB.  No need for ellipse.

I give you a cute little homework. Find the formula for the area of the triangle using the data you know and maybe post it in my replies  :)
